# Can temperature be objectively related to energy?

Tags: temperature

Temperature is disordered kinetic energy, with 0K being 0 Joules disordered kinetic energy, if I"m not mistaken. So, given required parameters(temperature, number of particles, mass of each particle, whatever is required) can you find the disordered kinetic energy of each particle?

Comment: I know that to raise the temperature of different substances by 1 degree it takes different amounts of energy, but that is because some energy becomes potential energy. So I want to how if potential energy didnt matter how much kinetic energy would be required.

Comment: The title asks a different question than the content. The title can be answered by "yes" if somebody gave all the particle kinetic energy and momentum vectors. The inverse ,"given the temperature ...." cannot be answered for the many body problem, as one cannot give from any statistical average  the labeled individual contribution, unless one knows where all data is completely recorded, which makes it a non problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware of the following relation: $\frac{1}{2}mv_{rms}^2=\frac{3}{2}kT$, but I think you will find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The velocity distribution is related to the temperature by the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). You cannot find the *disordered kinetic energy of each particle* because they are randomly distributed, however you can use the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution to calculate what that random distribution looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your idea is that 'whatever is required' contains data that CANNOT be determined sufficiently due to the uncertainty principle.

Funnily, the same thing that would make computation on particle level terribly complex due to the large number of particles involved, works in favor of the statistical approach that is compatible with said uncertainty principle, by making the statistics more reliable. (See the other answer i.e. Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution)